# flex core process window

Tags: apache-flex, process, window

if someone presses ctrl +alt +delete or any kind of shutdown hook from any os and delete the **flex process** from task manager then how can i track from that flex process application that killing that flex process was activated so i like to do some processing before killing this process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Killing the process will shut down the flash player before it has the chance to do anything.